# How can I combine SORT/ORDER and GROUP in one QUERY?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

In this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1De3JbEzr5aAghz7s0JbsT_V0X3cfI9jBgcG96i2JHAA/edit?usp=sharing) I combine results from a Google Form with this code:

```
    ={"Faglig vurdering for "& SUM(COUNTUNIQUE('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D; "*9M*"))&" elever i 9M";
 QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((LEN('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D))*('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C="9M");
 ('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D&CHAR(10)&
  'Formularsvar 1'!E2:E&CHAR(10)&
  'Formularsvar 1'!F1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$F$2:F&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!G1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$G$2:G&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!H1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$H$2:H&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!$I$2:I&CHAR(10)); ));"where Col1 is not null ORDER BY Col1"; 0)}
```

What I am trying to do is to SORT/ORDER and GROUP the result as illustrated in Desired Output in the [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1De3JbEzr5aAghz7s0JbsT_V0X3cfI9jBgcG96i2JHAA/edit?usp=sharing).

Is it possible to do one of the two output within a query or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: What is missing in the formula you have posted? Do you essentially want to group the results by the first name? And remove the name if it appears multiple times? If that is the situation, why not use other functions in order to make remove the non-unique/unnecessary values? @AllanBech

Comment: I think what I want is what you suggest; group multiple post by name but only show the name once. Can you recommend an other function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little formula for that:

```
=SORT(
  ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
      ARRAYFORMULA(
        {
          UNIQUE(FILTER('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D; REGEXMATCH('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C; "9M"))) & CHAR(10) \
          IF(
            UNIQUE(FILTER('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D; REGEXMATCH('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C; "9M"))) <> TRANSPOSE(FILTER('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D; REGEXMATCH('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C; "9M")));
              "";
              TRANSPOSE(FILTER(
                  'Formularsvar 1'!E2:E & CHAR(10)
                & 'Formularsvar 1'!F1   & " "
                & 'Formularsvar 1'!F2:F & " "
                & 'Formularsvar 1'!G1   & " "
                & 'Formularsvar 1'!G2:G & " "
                & 'Formularsvar 1'!H1   & " "
                & 'Formularsvar 1'!H2:H & " "
                & 'Formularsvar 1'!I2:I & CHAR(10) & CHAR(10);
                REGEXMATCH('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C; "9M")
              ))
          )
        }
      )
    ); ; ROWS(FILTER('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D; REGEXMATCH('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C; "9M"))) + 1));
    "\n +"; CHAR(10)
  ))
)
```

[image]

Comment: That is just a perfect solution. Thank you for ordering too :-)

Comment: ? Can I extend the name-column (D) to D:H?

Comment: @AllanBech I do not remember what the data looks like, and the example sheet is not shared anymore. Can't tell about extending `D` to `D:H` for sure.